# Как работает процессор на уровне Физики?

Tags: железо, cpu

Изучая C++ у меня возник вопрос, как устроен ПК и как так происходит, что он «понимает» данные ему команды? То есть как он понимает, что 2+2=4, он же не человек?

Comment: Это слишком сложная для обсуждения здесь тема. Подробно можно почитать, например, в книге Таненбаума "Архитектура Компьютера"

Comment: В разных областях этого "куска железа" разная плотность электронов. Их перетекание из одной части в другую трактуется как смена 0 на 1 и наоборот. При этом "куски железа" соединены весьма хитроумно, так чтобы 0 и 1-ки в одних местах влияли (в соответствии с булевой логикой) на 1-ки и нули в других.

Comment: Не железа, а кремния. Куча хитрым образом соединённых транзисторов. (А их вроде в школе проходят)

Comment: [Transistors, How do they work ?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ukDKVHnac4), [From Sand to Silicon: the Making of a Chip | Intel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q5paWn7bFg4)

Comment: [Building logic gates from MOSFET transistors](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1rZyGL1K5QI), [From NAND to Tetris: Building a Modern Computer From First Principles](http://nand2tetris.org/)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Если хотите узнать подробно, то советую почитать классический труд Тоненбаума - "Архитектура компьютера", где рассматриваются большинство уровней функционирования компьютера, начиная с самого низкого. Большинство схем ниже взяты оттуда.

В современных компьютерах есть такой электрический элемент, как транзистор. Он представляет из себя элемент с тремя ножками: коллектор, базу, эммитер. Но суть в том, что он умеет в зависимости от сигнала на базу, выпускать ток или нет.

[image: схема работы транзистора]

Сигнал на базу поступает из различных внешних источников - намагниченная дорожка жесткого диска, проходящий луч лазера через CD-R или же замкнутый нажатой кнопкой на клавиатуре контакт. Не важно, главное, что у нас теперь есть два состояния - есть сигнал и нет сигнала.

А теперь самое интересное, мы может комбинировать эти транзисторы и получить различные результаты на основе входящих на их базы сигналов.

[image: комбинирование вентилей для получения различных сигналов на выходе]

На самом деле вы же уже знакомы с булевой алгеброй, когда на вход подаются различные сигналы и получается в итоге другой? Ну так вот это оно и есть, это называется вентили.

[image: основные вентили]

А это значит, что теперь у нас есть целый конструктор! И на этом конструкторе мы может создавать различные схемы, которые будут давать разный результат. Подали на базы различные сигналы и получили на выходе результат.

Вот так выглядит схема сдвига и схема полусумматора. Объединив несколько полусумматоров, мы как раз получим побайтовое сложение чисел, о чем вы и спрашиваете в вопросе.

[image: схемы: сумматор и сдвиг]

Есть даже схемы, которые умеют хранить значение, так называемые защелки выполняющие роль памяти (RS-триггер).

[image: rs-триггер]

Как видите никакой магии, ну почти - на одном процессоре таких транзисторов умещается миллиарды... нет, не так - МИЛЛИАРДЫ! Это огромнейшее количество различных схем различной сложности и различного направления на паре квадратных сантиметров. Расчетом их упаковки на процессор как правило занимаются специальные программы, человеку это не под силу и создаются они с помощью высокоточной электроники. Сложно представимый научный прогресс в маленькой коробочке рядом с вами. В общем как-то так.